# Error in Installing spacy en_core_web_lg on Heroku app

Tags: python, django, heroku, spacy

Am deploying my ML model on Heroku using Django, I need `en_core_web_lg` for my application but couldn't install it

My requirements.txt is like:

```
..
..
djangorestframework==3.12.2
en-core-web-lg==2.3.1
en-core-web-sm==2.3.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
heroku==0.1.4
..
```

The Error is:

```
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement en-core-web-lg==2.3.1 (from -r /tmp/build_c3075f3c_/requirements.txt (line 14)) (from versions: none)
       ERROR: No matching distribution found for en-core-web-lg==2.3.1 (from -r /tmp/build_c3075f3c_/requirements.txt (line 14))
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Comment: It is possible that you do not have enough space left in your dyno. Check this out - heroku is not for compute, it is primarily for simple websites. I know the model itself is small (around 350MB), but see if your other deps already took up too much space - a free/hobby/standard has only 512mb, so you would only have 162 MB left - will your other deps fit here?

Comment: Yes! This link I got from one SO post but it's also not working. I just need the way to install this so that I can load it.

Comment: Does it install on your local machine?

Comment: There's no memory overlfow message.

Comment: Yes it's working fine on local machine. I installed it using spacy but how can I install it on heroku which uses pip only.

Comment: Open up a bash instance on the heroku dyno and see if you can download it that way, directly.

Comment: No it's not working.

Comment: What's the error message, please update the question with the error output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it is not installing direct from `requirements.txt` file. There is another way it is not right way but the work will go on.
First you have to remove the package from `requirements.txt` file  for which the error is coming.
Then push the app on `Heroku`, once your app have come to `Heroku` then write this code either from the `terminal` or from the `Heroku` `dashboard`.

If you are using `terminal` then:

```
heroku run bash
```

Then run:

```
pip install spacy
```

and then install which requiremts you want from spacy

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

if you are using `Heroku dashboard` then :
first go to your `Heroku dashboard` click on your app and then at top right click on `More` and select the `Run Console`
example image:

[image]
than this interface will come up
[image]
in this you have to click on `bash` or type `bash` and run
after this you can put same cammand and install.

Answer (score 9):

Your error is because there is no pip library named `en-core-web-lg`. Keep in mind that you cannot put `en-core-web-lg` in the `requirements.txt` since it is not a library that you can install using `pip`. They are models that spacy uses.

The accepted answer is fine. However, if you want a complete automatic deployment, you can also add something like this into your code:

```py
    try:
        nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
    except: # If not present, we download
        spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_md")
        nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
```

This will download the models automatically if they are not present. And, it will not require you to use the Heroku terminal. Only `spacy` on the `requirements.txt` file will be necessary.

Finally, keep in mind that spacy models are loaded in memory (RAM). The `lg` model (about 700MB) is too big to be fitted in a Free, Hobby or Standard 1X dynos (512MB of RAM). So it will fail to load and the dyno will be killed with R15 (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r15-memory-quota-vastly-exceeded).

More info about dynos: https://www.heroku.com/dynos

Comment: Yes, it works for other models too. I did use for `en_core_web_lg`, worked fine.