# Heroku deploy and install from wheel saved in git repo

Tags: heroku

Is there a way to install a dependency (listed in the requirements.txt) not from pypi but from a wheel saved in the git repo while deploying?
This question might sound odd at first, but it is simply due to the fact that I can not share the wheel on pypi.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)

Comment: Not really, I know how to install a wheel on my local machine. However, in this specific case I want to install it on the Heroku sever during the deploy process from a git wheel (not from pypi as usually done by referring to it in the requirements.txt).

Comment: first you deploy your application to Heroku than you can use Heroku Bash to install any requirements

Comment: @AnkitTiwari please send this as a solution, i made it work in this way.

Comment: Hello @ChrisChross sorry for late reply you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65550922/14457833 for using heroku bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you deploy your application to **Heroku** then you can use **Heroku Bash** to install any requirements
run this command for start your bash on heroku

```
heroku run bash
```