# Heroku Django Virtual Environment source code modification

Tags: python, django, mongodb, heroku

I managed to deploy my django app (with mongodb as database) on heroku.

But I need to modify some source code in django package in the virtual environment.

How can I access to virtual environment created by heroku from requirements.txt ?
Or maybe how can I upload directly the virtual environment to heroku and make sure that my GIT django app is working on it?

thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in Installing spacy en\_core\_web\_lg on Heroku app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65549200/error-in-installing-spacy-en-core-web-lg-on-heroku-app)

Comment: I assume you want to change something in a python package you are using. I wouldn't recommend changing the source code of your dependencies. It would be better to override functionality from within your own source code, or fork the package you're using. Could you outline the problem you're running into more specifically?

Comment: Updating the source code has nothing to do with the virtual environment, also requirements.txt can be used as template to create the environment, but also has nothing to do with activating the environment. If you want the source code to be updated, just update the code and rerun the python command/ herocku deploy

Comment: Hello all. Thanks for you reply. The problem I have is within django package 2.2 (not resolved in version 3) when I need to reed a file from mongodb (gridfs system), the django package return int(value), however the return from mongodb is not a numeric value (like in sql where pk is 1,2,3,....), rather its a objectid object... So I just remove the int in int(value) and it works.. Thats why I need to modify source code of django.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how would you know git dependencies match your local environment, first you should freeze your installed modules:

```py
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then include this file in the root directory of your app which will be deployed to heroku. After it is pushed to git, take a look at the commands run and verify the modules are installed.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The problem I have is within django package 2.2 (not resolved in version 3) when I need to read a file from mongodb (gridfs system), the django package returns int(value), however the return from mongodb is not a numeric value (like in sql where pk is 1,2,3,....), rather its a objectid object... So I just remove the int in int(value) and it works.. Thats why I need to modify source code of django.